# Javascript remove url last segment if found is numeric

Tags: javascript, url, segment

I have javascript function to map url and hyperlink to highlight menu items, however I can't do this in deeper page with url last segment come with number, which a url looks like: `http://localhost/story/89`

I want to remove the last url segment if it was a number, so the url will end up `http://localhost/story` (strip `/` as well).

```
/* highlight nav menu */
$(function(){
    $('#topMain li a').each(function(index) {
        if($.trim(this.href) == stripQueryStringAndHashFromPath(window.location.href)) {
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('active')
            .closest('li.parent').addClass('active');
        }
    });
});

function stripQueryStringAndHashFromPath(url) {
    return url.split("?")[0].split("#")[0];
}
```

Comment: What is your point in doing this anyways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass regular expression parameter into `split()`.

Just add `.split(/(\/\d*)$/)[0]` to the end of `url.split("?")[0].split("#")[0]` in your `stripQueryStringAndHashFromPath` function.

That new segment of regular expression basically search for a backslash (`\/`) that is followed by one or more digits (`\d*`) which is positioned at the end (`$`) of a string.

More about regular expression [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp).

```js
function stripQueryStringAndHashFromPath(url) {
    url = url.split('?')[0].split('#')[0].split(/(\/\d*)$/)[0];
    return url;
}

console.log(stripQueryStringAndHashFromPath('http://localhost/story/89'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function validateURL(url){ let lastSegment = url.split("/");
        if(lastSegment[(lastSegment.length)-1].match(/^[0-9]$/))
            console.log("True Last Segmant");
        }
    validateURL("http://localhost/demo/8")
```

```js
function stripQueryStringAndHashFromPath(url) {
    url = url.split('?')[0].split('#')[0].split(/(\/\d*)$/)[0];
    return url;
}

console.log(stripQueryStringAndHashFromPath('http://localhost/story/89'));
```

Answer (score 0):

function validateURL(url){ let lastSegment = url.split("/");if(lastSegment[(lastSegment.length)-1].match(/^[0-9]$/))console.log("True Last Segmant"); } validateURL("http://localhost/demo/8");

Comment: For validating the last segment you can use the below code: <script>
        function validateURL(url){
            let lastSegment = url.split("/");
            if(lastSegment[(lastSegment.length)-1].match(/^[0-9]$/))
                console.log("True Last Segmant");
            else
                console.log("False")
        }
        validateURL("http://localhost/demo/8")
        </script>